# Apache jmeter- How To Use ht password authentication

Tags: authentication, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to load test a site ,which is protected by ht-password ,i used the following methods

- http://username:password@site/path
- Name: Authorization
  Value: Basic [Base64-encoded username:password] string
- http Authorization Manager -username and password given

But i failed to pass authentication using all these methods

Can anyone help ??

Comment: first you should understand what mechanism is used by server to authenticate user. analyze the HTTP request (use Browser -> F12 -> Network tab) and check the headers which are responsible for authentication (like Cookie, Authentication etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of bypassing Basic HTTP Authentication is using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) configured like:

[image: HTTP Authorization Manager]

See [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) article for more details and example configuration.

Note: above options will work for [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/htpasswd.html)-based authentication (or equivalent) only, if your server uses other mechanism - you will need different configuration.

Comment: thanks it worked with http header manager using base 64 login values.. i changed the method from POST to GET and tried and get succeeded..